# mklink and JFolder: :folder: Path is not a folder [due to is_dir()]

Tags: php, xampp, symlink

Joomla is on Win2012 R2, XAMPP, Fabrik.
I created a symlink like so:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>mklink /D "C:\xampp\htdocs\pdf" "Z:\"
symbolic link created for C:\xampp\htdocs\pdf <<===>> Z:\
```

When I point the file upload element to the above directory, and I try to add a new record, there is the following error:

> JFolder: :folder: Path is not a folder.

Needless to say that even though it shows the form, it doesn't save it.

I did this so that I can save the PDFs on a LAN location.

I already assigned the administrator username and password to Apache in Services, it doesn't work.

How do I create symlinks in Win that Joomla will take as a directory, or how to disable the `is_dir()` check in Joomla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, and thanks to [Matthias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38267651/2943403) and [P.T.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46491362/2943403) @
[Using mklink command with network drives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21616431/2943403).

I did the second suggestion of the post first:

```
fsutil behavior set SymlinkEvaluation L2R:1
```

...so I'm not sure if it will work without it.

Like he said, just create 2 symlinks in Windows! :D

```
mklink /D D:\shareLink \\network\share
mklink /J D:\junctionLink D:\shareLink
```

In my case, I created a /D link to a linux server on a local network that the account can access
and
created a /J link to that /D link pointing to a htdocs/joomla/pdf
and all you have to do at the end is to say element - file upload, destination /pdf
and it works!!

If users follow these simple instructions, they can save and retrieve all their files on any server they want.

Be very, very careful when removing the symbolic links in Windows!

ref: https://superuser.com/questions/167076/how-can-i-delete-a-symbolic-link
You have to use rmdir for links created with /J, otherwise if you delete them with a "del" key, the directory and its files will be deleted.